# Looking For Datasets on U.S. City Locations for Data Science Project?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, machine-learning, nlp

I am currently working on a project that requires datasets detailing the locations of different cities across the United States. Specifically, I'm looking for data that includes city names along with their geographical coordinates (latitude and longitude) or any similar spatial data representations.

Before posting here, I searched through commonly known data sources like the U.S. Census Bureau and Data.gov but haven't found exactly what I need. My requirement is for a dataset that is comprehensive, up-to-date, and, ideally, includes additional demographic or geographic information about these cities.

Could anyone here guide me towards datasets that meet these criteria? Any pointers towards open data platforms, government databases, or other reliable sources for such data would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!